# What description should we give to the [provider] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I found [provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/provider) which has a link to a deleted question from 2013 on meta.stackexchange.com (deleted because it was off-topic over there). I don't have 10,000 reputation, so I'm taking the content from https://web.archive.org/web/20150924164137/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173498/what-to-do-with-the-provider-and-providers-tags:

> Currently, the [provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/provider) tag has 399 questions, and the [providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/providers) tag has 40 questions.
>
> There seems to be some confusion as what the tag is used for, since the newly-created excerpt for [providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/providers) states:
>
> > The provider model is a design pattern formulated by Microsoft for use in the ASP.NET Starter Kits and formalized in .NET version 2.0. It is used to allow an application to choose from one of multiple implementations or "condiments" in the application configuration, for example, to provide access to different data stores to retrieve login information, or to use different storage methodologies such as a database, binary to disk, XML, etc.
>
> which is clearly incorrect, since the tag is also used in conjunction with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), and pretty much anything else you can think of.
>
> So... does [provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/provider) need to get merged into [providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/providers)? The other way around? Tag synonym? Burninated? Something else?

Nowadays, [providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/providers) got cleaned up already, so it's time to update the tag description of [provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/provider). However, **I want to confirm first if  the .NET design pattern description given above is fine or not?**

Likely, it is not, so I want to understand what description it should be. Or if we're still in the process to cleanup the tag, 6 years later.

Comment: That earlier question was automatically deleted because it had no answer and a score of 0. The tag _still_ needs cleanup. Or if it's now solely about a single topic, it needs to be renamed. I have no idea to what, my only involvement to this topic was to link to the meta discussion from the tag wiki.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, you changed `>Currently` to `> Currently`, but left `>which` intact. Is that because of the capitalization? Is there an impact of such whitespace character in the markdown?

Comment: I say burninate the tag, if necessary use (or create) specific tags such as [tag:android-fileprovider]